# Magento 1: Skip payment depending on shipping method selected

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, shipping-methods

I have this problem where I need to skip payment options when a user choose flat rate shipping method and show payment if user choose other shipping method.

I looked for similar problem but couldn't find any. Can you guys suggest me a snippet or idea on how to achieve it?

Edit:

This question ([Filter Payment Method besed on Shipping Method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4225/filter-payment-method-besed-on-shipping-method)) is just hiding or removing specific payment method not skipping the payment method itself.

I just want to skip the whole payment method and continue to order review. Just skip the payment method.

Example:

Shipping Method => Flat rate (Selected and click continue button)
Payment Method => Skip (auto selected payment = Custom Payment)
Order Review Loaded

Update[09/29/2016]:

This post magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45166/… help a bit but doesn't really skip the payment itself. So what I did is auto select the payment and add javascript/jQuery script to fire automatically the continue button.

Thanks

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: It's different problem for my situation but thanks anyway.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Customers should not pay if they select flat rate shipping? Without the payment step you don't get money from them.

Comment: You probably forgot to mention some more details of your use case. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I actually renamed it to "Contact for more payment options" so we will contact the customer for further payment options after the order has been made. Thanks fschmengler.

Comment: This post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45166/setting-default-payment-method-and-skip-the-payment-step help a bit but doesn't really skip the payment itself. So what I did is auto select the payment and add javascript/jQuery script to fire automatically the continue button.

Comment: If anyone want's to know my code here it is: 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery("#p_method_pay").length){
      jQuery("#p_method_pay").prop( "checked", true );
      jQuery('#payment-buttons-container button.button').trigger( "click" );
    }
  });